# Flutter changing Icon onTap in my animated List

Tags: android, list, flutter

I'm trying to change my icon after I tap on my List Item. I already tried different things: I tried the onTap method but the icon just does not want to change. I'm very new to flutter and I would love to find some help for my problem :). Here is my code.

I already searched for solutions but I didn't got it working in my project

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'To-Do List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('To-Do List'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        ),
        body: BodyLayout(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyLayoutState createState() {
    return new BodyLayoutState();
  }
}

class BodyLayoutState extends State<BodyLayout> {

  // The GlobalKey keeps track of the visible state of the list items
  // while they are being animated.
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  // backing data
  List<String> _data = [];
  final _isdone = Set<String>();
 // bool selected = false;
  List<bool> selected = new List<bool>();
  Icon notdone = Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank);
  Icon done = Icon(Icons.check_box);

  TextEditingController todoController = TextEditingController();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 445,
          child: AnimatedList(
            // Give the Animated list the global key
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: _data.length,
            // Similar to ListView itemBuilder, but AnimatedList has
            // an additional animation parameter.
            itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
              // Breaking the row widget out as a method so that we can
              // share it with the _removeSingleItem() method.
              return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
            },
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: todoController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'To-Do'
          ),
        ),

        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Insert item', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          onPressed: () {
            _insertSingleItem();
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Remove item', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          onPressed: () {
            _removeSingleItem();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  // This is the animated row with the Card.
  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    final isdone = _isdone.contains(item);
    selected.add(false);
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          trailing: Icon(
           isdone ? Icons.check_box: Icons.check_box_outline_blank
          ),
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
             
            });
          },

        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void _insertSingleItem() {
    int insertIndex = 0;
    setState(() {
      _data.insert(0, todoController.text);
    });
    // Add the item to the data list.
    // Add the item visually to the AnimatedList.
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(insertIndex);
  }

  void _removeSingleItem() {
    int removeIndex = 0;
    // Remove item from data list but keep copy to give to the animation.
    String removedItem = _data.removeAt(removeIndex);
    // This builder is just for showing the row while it is still
    // animating away. The item is already gone from the data list.
    AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
      return _buildItem(removedItem, animation);
    };
    // Remove the item visually from the AnimatedList.
    _listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already mentioned the icons above. You simply need to use them instead of declaring new ones again.

```
// This is the animated row with the Card.
Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
  final isdone = _isdone.contains(item);
  selected.add(false);
  return SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: animation,
    child: Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          item,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        trailing: isdone ? done: notdone, // use the icon variables you have already defined
        onTap: (){
          setState(() {
            // add the item to _isdone set if it is not added and remove it if it is added when tapped on the list item
            if(isdone) {
              _isdone.remove(item);
            } else {
              _isdone.add(item);
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

In this code, I have added the item and removed the item in `setSate()` in the `onTap()`, so that whenever you tap the list item, `_isdone` `Set` gets updated and the `build()` is reloaded. Which makes your layout and data update itself every time you tap on the list item.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but after i clicked on the Item to change the Icon all other Items i add afterwards already have the changed Icon. Is there a way to only change the Icon of one Item in my list?

Comment: Ah, the problem is that if i add a new Item with a different string the Icon is not changed, but if a add a new Item with the same String i already changed. The Icon is still the changed one. For example in my ToDo list i add a item "Studying" then i click on it to change the icon to done. If i now add a new Item with the same String "Studying" it als has the changed icon done. If i add a different String it works all fine!

Comment: Yeah because in the code you're checking if the string in the list item is done or not.
So if there are two list items with the same name they both will be shown as checked or not checked together.